# Excel Need advice with a nested Formula I think?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the formula I came up with:

```
=IF(H6<=0.35,35,IF(H6>=0.36,ROUND(B6*0.02,0)))
```

H6 is the percent of the balance
I am trying to get it to do
$35 or 2% of balance seems to work under 35 but when it goes over it don't 
work properly I need it to read $35 if the 2% is less :(( Any help would be greatly appreciated :)).

Comment: Please reformat the body and add some relevant details about this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're after, e.g. what's in B6?

As you're dealing in percentages are you sure you want to round to 0 digits not 2 or something like that?

i.e. if you change to:

```
=IF(H6<=0.35,35,IF(H6>=0.36,ROUND(B6*0.02,2)))
```

does that fix it?

Also, if H6 is 0.351 your formula is going to produce FALSE, is that by intention?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback no that is not the intention. What I am trying to do is figure out a running total for my credit card where the min payment is $35 or 2% of the total. Lets say my balance is for the month is $600 the formula says I owe $12 I cant figure out if-else statement to take into account the minimum $35 payment. Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: So basically it's if 2% of your balance is less than $35 then make it $35?

Comment: If it's that then assuming your balance is in A1 then its `=IF(A1*0.02<35,35,A1*0.02)`

Comment: This may not be able to be done in excel but if A1 is less than 35 can it but that value? When I have a value of 0 it still owe 35. Would like to figure out a formula where A1 under 35 would be the value owed and take into consideration 0 is 0. Thanks for all your help

Comment: =IF(A1*0.02<35,IF(A1<35,A1,35),A1*0.02)

Comment: Tim, you are the man !! I am new on here or I  would up vote you for best answer but it wont let me. I really appreciate your help !!

Comment: You should be able to click the green tick to accept the answer.